# Denormalizing two column families in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, denormalization

I want to do a query in Cassandra that needs data from two column families. In sql we did it by foreign keys and joins but in Cassandra these concepts are not defined. So I want to denormalize two column families in Cassandra, but I do not know how to do it.
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe show us your schema?

Comment: I have two column families to denormalized..  First: Station (IDStation primary key, code, name, location, supervisor, citycode)..... Second: Information (IDInf primary key, IDstation, date, time, temprature, humidity, pressure)... please tell me how to denormalize these column families.. thanks

Comment: One last question, is the relationship between station and information 1..1 or can a station have multiple information entries?

Answer (score 1):

[Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) means you create a table based on the result of [join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) from multiple tables.

In your example, you have the following two tables:

```
Station (IDStation primary key, code, name, location, supervisor, citycode);
Information (IDInf primary key, IDstation, date, time, temprature, humidity, pressure);
```

where the Information has a foreign key to the Station table.  Their denormalized table is something like the following

```
StationInfo (
  IDStation, 
  code,
  name,
  location,
  supervisor,
  citycode, 
  IDInf,
  date,
  time,
  temprature,
  humidity,
  pressure,
  PRIMARY KEY (IDStation, IDInf)
);
```

where the same station with different information is a different station.

In case the relationship between Station and Information is 1:1 mapping, then they can be described using only one ID:

```
StationInfo (
  IDStation primary key, 
  code,
  name,
  location,
  supervisor,
  citycode, 
  date,
  time,
  temprature,
  humidity,
  pressure
);
```